# Windows events in iframe

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue application that runs in a iframe of a document. When the user tries to close a iframe, I want to prompt for saving changes. The below code is in my Vue application. The problem is that my parent window starts reacting to these events. Any ideas how this can work only within the iframe?

```
mounted(){
 window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
  if (this.isDirty() === false)
    event.returnValue = `Changes may not be saved. Are you sure you want to leave?`;
  });
},
beforeDestroy() {
 window.removeEventListener('beforeunload')
},
```

Comment: I would say if you close the parent, you also close the iframe it contains, right? Or do you think that the child iframe is setting the event handler on the parent?

Comment: There are no events on the parent and so if you close the parent, iframe would close as well and that is fine. My question concerning only when iframe is closed